# Can I code in Objective C in XCode 10

Tags: osx, ios

My client is asking for creating the iPhone app using Objective C instead of Swift. I know this is not a good idea. But I wonder can I write Objective C in XCode 10. 
Can someone please guide me the requirements for this. I mean which version of OS and XCode is required for Objective C coding.

Comment: Hi Shivani gupta, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Agreed. Fanbois should ask [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) ;-) Welcome aboard, I hope that you get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Objective C remains fully supported by Apple and there are a number of situations where Swift has not been fully thought out. That’s why Swift 5 is just being released.

Kinda like how so many people complain about C++ but just about every foundational application - operating systems, compilers, drivers - are written in C/C++.

ALL versions of XCode, for the foreseeable future will support Objective C.

Comment: I can feel your enthusiasm for helping others. However, this question is off-topic on this site and thus shouldn't be answered. Please refrain from answering off-topic questions on any SE sites.